# Center NavBar Text

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am trying to center my navbar text but failed. I have tried a lot of different ways and still couldn't get it worked.

My **CSS**:

```
.navBar {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.navBar a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 14px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

My **HTML**:

```
<nav>
    <div class="navBar">
        <a class="active" href="Main.html"> Main</a>   
        <a href="Menu.html"> Menu</a>
        <a href="Events.html"> Events</a>    
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center the text using `flexbox` as:

```
.navBar {
  ...
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
.navBar {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navBar a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 14px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
    <nav>
      <div class="navBar">
        <a class="active" href="Main.html"> Main</a>
        <a href="Menu.html"> Menu</a>
        <a href="Events.html"> Events</a>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you tons.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```css
.navBar {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}

.navBar a {
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="navBar">
    <a class="active" href="Main.html"> Main</a>   
    <a href="Menu.html"> Menu</a>
    <a href="Events.html"> Events</a>    
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.navBar a {
 display: inline-block;
}
```